# Can't make static reference, even if nothing is static?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a nice class. It has a nice inner class. That inner class has some nice public variables.

How can I use the variables of the inner class in the constructor of the outer class?

```
public class Outer {
    class Inner {
        public int id;
        public Inner () { }
    }

    public Outer () {
        System.out.println(Inner.id); // Error!
    }
}
```

"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Inner.id."

This project is using Gson; the class Inner and its property id are defined by some JSON, like so:

```
{
    "Outer": {
        "Inner": {
            "id": 0
        }
    }
}
```

I then call serialize it using Gson like normal.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Outer o = gson.fromJson(json, Outer.class);
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I can change Inner to a static class along with id, but that makes Gson throw up. I can set static getters and setters, but that doesn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make id static if you want to refer to it that way.

Answer (score 4):

All the above suggestions are right answers but I will recommend that your inner class should be static. Because

An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance.

To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't think making it static will let it play nice with Gson. Their docs are [kinda confusing](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Comment: Just to add a little detail, `Inner.id` is a static reference since you reference the class, and not an instance of the class, hence the error.

Comment: _"To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this"_

Can you make an example?

Comment: check this OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();

Comment: also this you can find that in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @AndrewRabon It is clear that from the link you have provided "Gson can serialize static nested classes quite easily". And " Gson can not automatically deserialize the pure inner classes since their no-args constructor also need a reference to the containing Object which is not available at the time of deserialization". You have to be clear about what is "static inner class" and "pure inner class", pure inner class isn't static inner class

Comment: @Pragnani So would you suggest I do something like:

    ...
    static class Inner {
        ...

?

Comment: @AndrewRabon yup...That what you need to do, according to GSON documentation

Comment: @Pragnani I did that, but now using "new Inner().id" in Outer's constructor is throwing a NullPointerException.

Comment: @AndrewRabon use Inner.id,

Answer (score 0):

try to use System.out.println(`new` Inner().id);

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(new Inner().id);